# Adding a disk to folder management in Picasa, Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, picasa

I would like to add a whole disk (FAT32) to [Picasa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picasa) folder management.  It's a data disk my girlfriend (using Windows) and I share.  But I can only add folders from the disk Picasa (and Ubuntu) is installed on. How can I add a whole disk to folder management?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't ever used Picasa, but I would suggest that you [add the disk to your filesystem in Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MountWindowsSharesPermanently).

Then it is the same as using a local folder, and is also available to any other programs that you wish to use.

Comment: Of course, the disk is already visible (at locations), and I use it a lot to play mediafiles but this is maybe not the same, I will try your suggestion later, and will of course accept your answer if it works out.